# How to find and modify specific entity or gameobject in Hybrid ECS?

Tags: unity, entity-component-system, unity-dots

I am rotating 3 cubes in Unity with Hybrid ECS and the code goes like this :

```
public class RoatateECS : MonoBehaviour {
    public float moveSpeed = 10f;
}

class RotateSystem : ComponentSystem {

struct RoadComponets {
    public Transform transform;
    public RoatateECS rotateECS;
}
protected override void OnUpdate() {
    foreach(var e in GetEntities<RoadComponets>()) {
           e.transform.Rotate(0f, e.rotateECS.moveSpeed, 0f);
        } 

    }
}
```

Inside OnUpdate all three cubes are rotating, I want to rotate the second cube in the opposite direction but how would I find a specific cube and modify it ?